Meaning of "lui" in this sentence?
In Guillaume Musso's La Vie Secrète des écrivains there's the following passage

À cette époque, Apolline et Karim ont perpétré une palanquée de cambriolages. Lui était camé jusqu'à la moelle. Il leur fallait du cash tout le temps.

I think "lui" is referring to Karim (Karim Amrani), and I think "Lui, il était camé jusqu'à la moelle" would make sense here. Is the pronoun "il" omitted here, or what's going on?

Lui is indeed referring to Karim and it is the subject of était. Having the tonic pronoun as a subject is used to mark an opposition between two subjects.  See Les pronoms toniques utilisés comme sujets. Having il as well would be possible (but redundant) here, but il on its own would take on a slightly different meaning (not enough context of what comes after to say more).

I would not write "Lui, il était camé jusqu'à la moëlle" although it's 100% grammatical; maybe "Quant à lui, il était camé jusqu'à la moëlle". On the other hand, I wouldn't write "moelle" either, even though it's 100% orthographic.

Or maybe "Lui? Il était camé jusqu'à la moëlle".

Lui, it était camé jusqu'à la moëlle me paraît très bien, avec emphase sur lui, mis en valeur par cette virgule. Peut-être un peu familier et moins formel à l'écrit, mais tout à fait possible à mon avis. Quant à lui est possible aussi, mais plus "lourd", ça dépend du style voulu.

Puisque l'auteur utiliser déjà les mots camé et cash, le style n'est peut-être pas si soutenu.

I feel @None's link essentially answers the question. "Lui" is grammatical here, I had just missed this in studying the grammar.
